# How to highlight or change color of text within iOS?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsstring, uitextview

I would like to highlight or change the color of certain words within text, like when you search for a term, you get the highlighted words within search results.
I know I can't do this with NSStrings, but How will I able accomplish this? I would like to display text in UITextView, but can do other options if I need to.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 6 you *can* do it, because iOS 6 now allows UITextView (as well as UILabel, UIButton etc.) to display styled text (NSAttributedString). You color the word with `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` and color its background with `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` and presto, there's your highlight. There are several very good WWDC 2012 videos on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think right now will be using an UIWebView and using CSS and javascript to highlight words.

You can check this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8644513/454165) fo an example of how to highlight text with jQuery and CSS.

Also you can check this [example](http://www.nsftools.com/misc/SearchAndHighlight.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using EgoTextView, you can change color for range of texts. Please check the code [here](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/egotextview).