# How can I make the ctrl+f highlight effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a simple search function with highlight effect, however, it highlight the whole word instead of the matched strings.

How can I make it like doing ctrl+f in browser that highlights just part of the matched word?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').keyup(function(){

       $("ul li").removeClass('hightlight');

       var searchInput = $(this).val();

        if(searchInput !== ""){
           $("ul li:contains('" + searchInput + "')").addClass('hightlight');
        }

    });
});
```

My code online:

http://jsfiddle.net/dennisboys/5ZEf7/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to highlight text using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').keyup(function(){

       var searchInput = $(this).val();

       $('.hightlight').contents().unwrap();

       if(searchInput !== ""){
            $("ul li:contains('" + searchInput + "')").each(function(i, e) {
                var text = $(this).text().replace(new RegExp(searchInput, 'gm'), '<span class="hightlight">' + searchInput + '</span>');
                $(this).html(text);
            })
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: If a word contains two occurence of search string it will highlight first only unlike chrome where all occurences are highlight. I hope you can do this withe ease

Comment: Yep, I missed it, thank you for reminder =) Replaced search string with regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working demo with the required HTML and css. http://jsfiddle.net/BHqTr/

```
$("#search").on( "keyup", function() {

        $("#items li span").contents().unwrap();

        $("#items li").each(function(){
            var search = $("#search").val();
            var item = $(this);

            var text = item.text();

            var regex = new RegExp(search, 'g');
            text = text.replace(regex, "<span class='highlight'>"+search+"</span>");
            item.html(text);
        });
    });
```

EDIT:

This looks like a copy of the previous answer, can be removed if required.

Comment: Great! Have you read other answers before post your own? You just posted almost complete duplicate.

Comment: @AlexG.P. haha, didn't notice that.