# highlighting all matching words in div from text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a function which highlights matching words in a div. but if there are two identical words separated by a different word then only the first word is highlight. so for example if the search criterion was the word "burn", and in the text was the sentence "burn baby burn", I would want it to highlight both "burn"'s. this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhLQ7/) demonstrates how it only highlights the first "burn". Here is the code below also. Any help much appreciated. Thanks for reading.

css

```
.highlight{
            font-weight:bold;
            color:green;
}
```

html

```
<input id = "search" type ="text" value = "burn">
<div class = "searchable">burn baby burn</div>
```

javascript

```
if($('#search').val().length !== 0){
   $('.searchable').each(function(){
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace($('#search').val(),"<span class = 'highlight'>"+$('#search').val()+"</span>"));
 });
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass a regular expression into replace() instead of the string, with the g modifier to make replace perform a global match.

```
if($('#search').val().length !== 0){
   $('.searchable').each(function(){
   var search_value = $("#search").val();
   var search_regexp = new RegExp(search_value, "g");
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace(search_regexp,"<span class = 'highlight'>"+search_value+"</span>"));
 });
}
```

Answer (score 9):

1. Take care of [regex special characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters).
2. Maintain uppercase & lowercase.

So taking care of above things with case insensitive search (in most cases, this is desired; otherwise just remove "i"), here is the final code...

```
if ($('#search').val().length !== 0) {
    $('.searchable').each(function() {
        //Handle special characters used in regex
        var searchregexp = new RegExp($("#search").val().replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'), "gi");

        //$& will maintain uppercase and lowercase characters.
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(searchregexp, "<span class = 'highlight'>$&</span>"));
    });
}
```

[And a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssh4q1ye/2/).

Comment: This answer also handles special characters in the search string.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtq2C/) for you. Basically, get the text from the div, split it on space, loop through the words and see if one matches.

```
var term = $('#search').val().trim().toLowerCase();
if (term.length > 0) {
    var source = $('.searchable').text();
    var words = source.split(' ');
    var output = '';
    $.each(words, function(idx, word) {
        if (term === word.toLowerCase()) {
            output += '<span class="highlight">' + word + '</span> ';
        } else {
             output += word + ' ';   
        }
    });

    $('.searchable').html(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression with :

- global 'g' flag to replace all the matches
- ignore case 'i' to match all cases

Do not forget to escape special characters

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
const SEARCH_VALUE = $("#search").val().trim();

if (SEARCH_VALUE.length > 0) {
  $('.searchable').each(function() {
    const DIV_TEXT_CONTENT = $('.searchable').text();
    const SPLIT_CONTENT = DIV_TEXT_CONTENT.split(" ");

    SPLIT_CONTENT.forEach((word, index) => {
      const SEARCH_REGEXP = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(SEARCH_VALUE), "gi")
      if (SEARCH_REGEXP.test(word))
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(SEARCH_REGEXP, "<span class = 'highlight'>" + word + "               </span>"));
    });
  })
}

function escapeRegExp(text) {
  return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" type="text" value="BuRn">
<div class="searchable">burn baby burn</div>
```