# Compare string with HTML text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I have a string of text that I want to compare with another string that has HTML code. The problem is that the text I need to compare it to in the HTML code is within different tags. Also, if the string exists in the HTML code then I want to wrap it inside a `<mark>` tag.

This is the example I am using:

```
var html = "<h1>This is a heading</h1><div class="subtitle">and this is the subheading</div><p class="small">this is some example text</p>";
var lookup = "is a heading and this is the subheading this is some";
var finalHtml = ""; //will contain new html

//Need to do some comparison and then add a <mark> tag around found string.

console.log(finalHtml);
//This should print "<h1>This <mark>is a heading</h1><div class="subtitle">and this is the subheading</div><p class="small">this is some</mark> example text</p>"
```

I am using Javascript/Jquery to do this.

Comment: You'd need to remove the HTML before making the comparison. ***However*** you should note that your desired output is invalid as the `<mark>` element breaks the `h1` and `p` elements.

Comment: **check this..** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493700/highlighting-all-matching-words-in-div-from-text-input

Comment: @Rory McCrossan - how can I highlight that text through HTML without making it invalid?

Comment: Also, once I remove the HTML and make the comparison, how can I add highlighting and then turn it back into HTML with the original tags etc?

Comment: You'd need to split the `mark` between elements, eg: `<h1>This <mark>is a heading</mark></h1><div class="subtitle"><mark>and this is the subheading</mark></div><p class="small"><mark>this is some</mark> example text</p>"`

Answer (score 0):

This will only help to search your lookup within html (i.e., no marking). I have removed tags-spaces & then checked.

```
var html = '<h1>This is a heading</h1><div class="subtitle">and this is the subheading</div><p class="small">this is some example text</p>';
//remove html tags & spaces.
cleanHtml = html.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "").replace(/\s/g,"");
var lookup = "is a heading and this is the subheading this is some";
lookup = lookup.replace(/\s/g,'');
if(cleanText.includes(lookup)){
//match found
}
```