# jQuery scrollTo text or scrollTo String

Tags: jquery, html, string, text

I have this string like:

> Life is a characteristic distinguishing physical entities having
>   signaling and self-sustaining processes from those that do not,[1][2]
>   either because such functions have ceased (death), or because they
>   lack such functions and are classified as inanimate.[3][4][5] Biology
>   is a science concerned with the study of life.
>
> The smallest contiguous unit of life is called an organism. Organisms
>   are composed of one, or more, cells, undergo metabolism, maintain
>   homeostasis, can grow, respond XXXXXX to stimuli, reproduce and, through
>   evolution, adapt to their environment in successive generations.[1] A
>   diverse array of living organisms can be found in the biosphere of
>   Earth, and the properties common to these organisms—plants, animals,
>   fungi, protists, archaea, and bacteria—are a carbon- and water-based
>   cellular form with complex organization and heritable genetic
>   information.
>
> The Earth was formed about 4.54 billion years ago. The earliest life
>   on Earth existed at least 3.5 billion years ago,[6][7][8] during the
>   Eoarchean Era when sufficient crust had solidified following the
>   molten Hadean Eon. The earliest physical evidence for life on Earth is
>   biogenic graphite in 3.7 billion-year-old metasedimentary rocks
>   discovered in Western Greenland[9] and microbial mat fossils found in
>   3.48 billion-year-old sandstone discovered in Western Australia.[10][11] Nevertheless, several studies suggest that life on
>   Earth may have XXXXXXXXX started even earlier,[12] as early as 4.25 billion
>   years ago according to one study,[13] and even earlier yet, 4.4
>   billion years ago, according to another study.[14] The mechanism by
>   which life began on Earth is unknown, although many hypotheses have
>   been formulated. Since emerging, life has evolved into a variety of
>   forms, which biologists have classified into a hierarchy of taxa. Life
>   can survive and thrive in a wide range of conditions.
>
> Though life is confirmed only on the Earth, many think that
>   extraterrestrial life is not only plausible, but probable or
>   inevitable.[15][16] Other planets and moons in the Solar System have
>   been examined for evidence of having once supported simple life, and
>   projects such as SETI have attempted to detect radio transmissions
>   from possible alien civilizations. According to the panspermia
>   hypothesis, `XXXXXXXXXX`microscopic life exists throughout the Universe, and is
>   distributed by meteoroids, asteroids and planetoids.[17]
>
> The meaning of life—its significance, origin, purpose, and ultimate
>   fate—is a central concept and question in philosophy and religion.
>   Both philosophy and religion have offered interpretations as to how
>   life relates to existence and consciousness, and on related issues
>   such as life stance, purpose, conception of a god or gods, a soul or
>   an afterlife. Different `XXXXXXXXXXXXX`cultures throughout history have had widely
>   varying approaches to these issues.

I have the following elements:

```
<input type="button" value="Prev" id="P" name="P">
<input type="button" value="Next" id="N" name="N">
```

and a Textarea

`<textarea id="enterAnyText"></textarea>`

When the user clicks on that input `#P`, the page should `scroll` to the previous `XXXXXXXXX` or *whatever text they(the user) inserted in the `textarea`*, with a nice animation.

When the user clicks on that input `#N`, the page should `scroll` to the next `XXXXXXXXX`or *whatever text they(the user) inserted in the `textarea`*,  with a nice animation.

The `animation` should not be too much fast and should be fluid.

I am running the latest `jQuery` version and there is no database.

The text is randomly generated from different story books... so XXXXXXX might signify any `word`, `string` or `text` they want to search inside the randomly generated looong text from a story book.

**PLEASE NOTE: The story books are save in `.html` files i.e `story1.html`, `story2.html.`... They are loaded inside `divs` using `jQuery.load()`**

**EDIT2: We tried to use i.e. `jQuery("p:contains(txt)")` but that scrolls to the parent `p` tag not the text or word itself**

a paragraph like:

> The Earth was formed about 4.54 billion years ago. The earliest
>   life on Earth existed at least 3.5 billion years ago,[6][7][8] during
>   the Eoarchean Era when sufficient crust had solidified following the
>   molten Hadean Eon. The earliest physical evidence for life on Earth is
>   biogenic graphite in 3.7 billion-year-old metasedimentary rocks
>   discovered in Western Greenland[9] and microbial mat fossils found in
>   3.48 billion-year-old sandstone discovered in Western Australia.[10][11] Nevertheless, several studies suggest that life on
>   Earth may have a paragraph like:
>       The Earth was formed about 4.54 billion years ago. The earliest life on Earth existed at least 3.5 billion years ago,[6][7][8] during
>   the Eoarchean Era when sufficient crust had solidified following the
>   molten Hadean Eon. The earliest physical evidence for life on Earth is
>   biogenic graphite in 3.7 billion-year-old metasedimentary rocks
>   discovered in Western Greenland[9] and microbial mat fossils found in
>   3.48 billion-year-old sandstone discovered in Western Australia.[10][11] Nevertheless, several studies suggest that life on
>   Earth may have  a paragraph like:
>       The Earth was formed about 4.54 billion years ago. The earliest life on Earth existed at least 3.5 billion years ago,[6][7][8] during
>   the Eoarchean Era when sufficient crust had solidified following the
>   molten Hadean Eon. The earliest physical evidence for life on Earth is
>   biogenic graphite in 3.7 billion-year-old metasedimentary rocks
>   discovered in Western Greenland[9] and microbial mat fossils found in
>   3.48 billion-year-old sandstone discovered in Western Australia.[10][11] Nevertheless, several studies suggest that life on
>   Earth may have XXXXXXXXX

will `scroll` to the `p` but not the `XXXXXXXXXXX`

Any suggestion is highly praised.

Comment: if jQuery("p:contains(txt)") works for you, then you can put the user entered text inside a span. So you'll easily get the offset of each span contains the user entered text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could potentially do it this way.

### HTML

```
<p>Here is a paragraph</p>
</p>Here is another paragraph</p>

<input type="button" value="previous" id="previous" />
<input type="text" placeholder="enter a searchstring" />
<input type="button" value="next" id="next" />
```

Keep in mind that this HTML won't actually scroll as its probably a lot shorter than your screen. Instead of scrolling, add a console log in the code below to see that it is pointing to right position from the top.

### jQuery

```
// the following function will search for all 'tags' containing 'value' in DOM order
var working = false;
function searchWordsReturnOffsets(value, tags){
    // this will prevent the function from executing while its still in an execution cycle.
    if(working) return;
    else working = true;
    var all = [];
    $(tags).each(function(){
        if($(this).text().indexOf(value) >= 0){
            // temporarily wrap them in a findable object we can locate
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace(value,"<span class='searchvalue'>" + value + "</span>"));
            // lets do another foreach to find every instances' offset
            $(this).find("span.searchvalue").each(function(){
                all.push($(this).offset().top);
            });
            // remove the findable objects again
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace("<span class='searchvalue'>" + value + "</span>",value));
        }
    });
    return all;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var current = 0;
    var positions = [];
    $("#search").on("keyup", function(){
        // here we will keep track of the paragraphs and reset to the first
        positions = searchWordsReturnOffsets($(this).val(), "p");
        current = 0;
        $("body,html").animate({scrollTop : positions[current]});
    });
    $("#next").click(function(){
        if(positions[current + 1] != undefined){
            current++;
            $("body,html").animate({scrollTop : positions[current]});
        }
    });
    $("#previous").click(function(){
        if(positions[current - 1] != undefined){
            current--;
            $("body,html").animate({scrollTop : positions[current]});
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var working = false;
function searchWordsReturnOffsets(value, tags){
    if(working) return;
    else working = true;
 var all = [];
 $(tags).each(function(){
  if($(this).text().indexOf(value) >= 0){
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace(value,"<span class='searchvalue'>" + value + "</span>"));
    $(this).find("span.searchvalue").each(function(){
           all.push($(this).offset().top);
       });
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace("<span class='searchvalue'>" + value + "</span>",value));
  }
 });
    working = false;
 return all;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 var current = 0;
 var positions = [];
    $("#search").on("keyup", function(){
     positions = searchWordsReturnOffsets($(this).val(), "p");
     current = 0;
        if(positions[current] != undefined){
          console.log(positions[current]);
        }
    });
    $("#next").click(function(){
     if(positions[current + 1] != undefined){
      current++;
            console.log(positions[current]);
     }
    });
    $("#previous").click(function(){
     if(positions[current - 1] != undefined){
      current--;
            console.log(positions[current]);
     }
    });
})
</script>

<p>Here is a paragraph</p>
<p>Here is another paragraph<br/>With a second line to see we get three results when searching 'ere'.</p>

<input type="button" value="previous" id="previous" />
<input type="text" placeholder="enter a searchstring" id="search" />
<input type="button" value="next" id="next" />
```

Comment: Please I beg for a Fiddle.... looks great though... Please Fiddle it up!!!... Thank you

Comment: I get error: `TypeError: $(...).find(...).offset(...) is undefined` and add the `id="search"` to the `textarea`

Comment: The code won't work: `$().text(...<span>...)` will escape the HTML code. For solutions, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript

Comment: @AaronDigulla I know, I used jQuery `.text()` and I should us `.html()`. I have amended the function so it now temporarily wraps your results in span tags and adds the offsets of those to the array. I have not thought about having multiple tags in the same paragraph yet, but that can be amended by adding a `foreach` '.searchvalue' and adding those offsets of the top.

Comment: Idea for an improvement: Assign IDs to the `span`, then you can scroll to them using the ID (i.e. leave the span in the text). If you assign a class to all of them, you can easily remove them when you search again.

Comment: @AaronDigulla the problem with that is that you will get a whole bunch IDs that never get cleaned up. By using a class you can find the word, find the offset of a newly wrapped element, remove the element and save the offset. This makes sure you don't get overly jumbled code. I also think the indexOf won't work otherwise...

Comment: I used this Text... http://pastebin.com/RPambNY6 it simply logs certain numbers and does nothing else... please HELP

Comment: @somethinghere: Don't the IDs die with the `<span>` when I remove them?

Comment: @somethinghere is there a way to have the m`acthed` Highlighted using your CODES if `scrolling` will be kinda Heard...??.... Please Help!!

Comment: @UniversalGrasp Scrolling: the values that are being reported are the offsets from the top of every match. Use something like `$("body,html").animate({scrollTop: [VALUE] + "px"});` to make it scroll. You could potentially keep the span tags, but removing the spans and replacing them by their original text again is a bit more complicated of a process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:contains()` to find specific text:

```
var target  = $( "div:contains('text to search for')" );
```

Then find the offset of `target` and scroll to it.

Caution, `:contains` finds all instances of the text in the page so which one you scroll to might be interesting.

Comment: Please see EDIT2... Thnak You though