# Highlight text in javascript like Evernote Web Clipper

Tags: javascript, html, highlight, evernote

My current solution is:

1. Get selected html (include text and html tag), namely: selText
2. highlightText = `<span>selText</span>`
3. Find `selText` in `innerHTML` of the body or document (or the element which the mouse dragged in)
4. Replace with `highlightText`

But if the document is: `a a a a a a` and user selects the last `a`. My function will highlight the first or all `a`.

Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: [**Check this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript), I think this will help you.
Exact same requirement.

Comment: I think your link is same requirement. But not specific the problem. The solution in that link is same with my solution, but I need an improvement

Comment: So you can modify/update it according to your requirement. Nobody will code for you.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. I need a suggestion, not for codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your question is duplicated, anyway i just searched the internet and found this [article](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1075/javascript-highlighting-selected-text).

Below the final code to achieve what you ask

```
function highlightSelection()  {
  var selection;

  //Get the selected stuff
  if(window.getSelection) 
    selection = window.getSelection();
  else if(typeof document.selection!="undefined")
    selection = document.selection;

  //Get a the selected content, in a range object
  var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

  //If the range spans some text, and inside a tag, set its css class.
  if(range && !selection.isCollapsed)
  {
    if(selection.anchorNode.parentNode == selection.focusNode.parentNode)
    {
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      span.className = 'highlight-green';
      range.surroundContents(span);
    }
  }
}
```

I also found this library [rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) that is an helper you can use to select text but only works with jquery so i prefer the first vanilla-js solution.

```
var el = $("<span></span>");
el.text(rangy.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).toString());
rangy.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).deleteContents();
rangy.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).insertNode(el.get(0));
rangy.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getSelection().setSingleRange(range);
```

**On Range and User Selection**

You have to select range using [Document.createRange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.createRange) that return a Range object before you can use [Range.surroundContents()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range.surroundContents), you could create a range this way.

```
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
range.setEnd(endNode, endOffset);
```

In practice you follow [this guide](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html) to understand range and selection tecniques.
The most important point is contained in this code

```
var userSelection;
if (window.getSelection) {
    userSelection = window.getSelection();
}
else if (document.selection) { // should come last; Opera!
    userSelection = document.selection.createRange();
}
```

After this you can use

```
userSelection.surroundContents()
```

Comment: Yeah, your `highlightSelection` function works with `#textnode`. Unfortunately, the `surroundContents` doesn't work when I select like this: `this is <a>a link</a>`. With your suggestion, now I can get a list of user selected #textnode, but I don't know how to wrap / surround it into a highlight span. Anw, thank you so much.

Comment: I added more info to understand how to use surroundContents, you have to create a Range object from the userSelection before you can use that method. Please flag the answer as resolved if this solves your issue.

Comment: Yeah, I will. I get the idea from your answer: process on `range` object, not on extracted text or htmlText. Thank you