# How to highlight text in a html string without breaking tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, highlight

Problem: Given any html string, how to highlight a substring in the text, but make sure tags are untouched?

For example replace the substring "brown":

```
str='<img src="brown fox.jpg" title="The brown fox" /><p>some text containing brown.</p>';
```

or

```
str='<p>some <span style="color:brown">text containing brown</span></p>';
```

How to highlight the substring brown in the text, but not inside the tags (to avoid breaking the tag.

This question originally surfaced here as an answer [How to highlight text using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript)

My solution is to split the string along tags, and replace only parts that are odd in the array (in between tags), but I wonder if there are any gotchas (one I can think of is invalid html, but that should be handled prior to handling the text IMHO)

```
var str='<p>some <span style="color:brown">text containing brown</span></p>';

//split along tags
var parts = str.split(/[<>]+/);

//remove empty
parts = parts.filter(function(n){ return n != ""}); 

for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
if (i%2 !== 0)
//console.log(parts[i]);
parts[i] = parts[i].replace("brown", "red whatever");
}

console.log(parts);
```

Output

```
["", "p", "some ", "span style="color:brown"", "text containing red whatever", "/span", "", "/p", ""]
```

Comment: self closing tags would be an issue: <br/>. i'd try to use jquery and selectors as much as possible for these replacements and then export the resulting dom html.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can access the DOM rather than manipulating the string directly,  you can access the text of any dom node by doing

```
$(selector).text()
```

Assign that text to a variable and manipulate it to your hearts content, 
then call

```
 $(selector).text(variable)
```

to change the text in the DOM.