# Live text highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am new with JavaScript trying to find solution for my problem.
Is there any way I can live highlight my text like we do in PDF's ?

Something like this: **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PeEySbC2ApIeNcyS6he6?p=preview)**

### Relevant Code

```
<div class="box">
   llentesque volutpat tempus eleifend. Integer viverra erat ante. Aliquam    
   gravida ac nibh non sollicitudin.
 </div>

<button type="button">highlight</button>
```

I have a button which allow/enable text highlighting on click. Then I drag my mouse selecting texts will get yellow background color.

Is this possible ? Any example will really help.
Thanks

### Demo

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { });
```

```css
.box span {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="box">llentesque volutpat tempus eleifend. Integer viverra erat ante. Aliquam gravida ac nibh non sollicitudin.</div>
  <button type="button">highlight</button>
  <div class="box" style="margin-top:100px">
    DEMO:
    <br>llentesque volutpat tempus eleifend. Integer viverra erat ante. <span>Aliquam gravida ac nibh non sollicitudin.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible with JavaScript...

Comment: Do you have any example how can I make this ?

Comment: I can give you an idea. With `window.getSelection().toString()` you can get the selected text. Now on button click, find this part and wrap it in a span element which has a background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stack Overflow entry covers numerous methods for highlighting text on a page using javascript:

[How to highlight text using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript)

If this isn't what you wanted, comment below.

Comment: Thanks for this article. I am following the instruction if I can make it works

Comment: If it proves to be a good solution, mark this response as the answer to your question so it makes it more visible to others who have the same question. Thanks!

Comment: Link is no longer available. This answer is useless.

Answer (score 1):

[here's](https://jsfiddle.net/syqe52ue/) a quick example that I made for you to play with. Basically you want some sort of event, I think `on('input')` works well here, and then check to see if there is a `<span>` element somewhere.

This is not a complete example of course, and could use some more work, but it should get you started.

```js
$('#textarea').on('input', function() {
    var text = $('#textarea').val();
    $('#result').html(text);
    if ($('#result').html().indexOf('<span>') > -1) {
        $('span:not(.highlighted)').addClass('highlighted');
    }
});

// Set the value initially and trigger the event.
$('#textarea').val('Hello <span>World</span>.').trigger('input');
```

```css
textarea {
    width: 196px;
    height: 100px;
}
#result {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.highlighted {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='textarea'></textarea>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: I added your external demo inline so others don't have to navigate away from Stack Overflow.

Comment: I point: I added span in the example to make it look like how I wanted. There should not be any span. This is something like: After I click the button it will enable highlighting mode and then Drag my mouse selecting the texts. Texts background will get yellow up I selected.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean