# How to highlight lowercase letters with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

For a paragraph like this

```
<p> This is an exaMPLe </p>
```

how to highlight the lowercase letters with a different color using Javascript?

Comment: @Hacketo quite new to Javascript, checking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript and http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/search-highlight/

Comment: @Hacketo need at least some startup ideas, hence the question; thanks for asking :)

Comment: iter all letters, test if letter.[toLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) === letter, then wrap it around a span

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty solution using regex find/replace.

```
var p = document.querySelector("p");
var html = p.innerHTML;

html = html.replace(/([a-z]+)/g, "<strong>$1</strong>");

p.innerHTML = html;
```

First, you get the paragraph, read its inner HTML. Then use regex to find lowercase a-z letters and wrap them with `strong` HTML tags. You can also use `span` and apply a CSS class if you wish. After regex find/replace, set back the HTML value.

Working example: http://jsbin.com/vodevutage/1/edit?html,js,console,output

**EDIT**:
If you wish to have a different colour, then change the one line as follows:

```
html = html.replace(/([a-z]+)/g, "<span class='highlight'>$1</span>");
```

and also define a CSS class as follows:

```
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Just for completion: If you want to highlight by giving a background color without spaces being skipped, then you have to change the regex to this `/([a-z, \s]+)/g`. But if you want to exclude spaces, the solution is absolutely correct :)

Comment: Your regex also matches commas. And you have space defined twice - once as a space, and once as `\s`, which matches any white space character. If you wanted to only add spaces, then `/([a-z ]+)/g` is the way to go.