# javascript highlight word on base of index sent to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to highlight the specific word index passed by function, initially function added on a button click.
The problem is when i reassign '**document.getElementById('inputText').innerHTML = filterText;**'
it re-renders the page(Because there is iframe video ) and there is an iframe and another thing which are conflicting.

```
function makeALlIndex() {
    defaultText = document.getElementById('inputText').innerHTML;
}

function changeColor(index, word) {
    myText = defaultText;
    var filterText = myText.substr(0, index) + '<span  class="highlightClass">' + word + '</span>' + myText.substr(index + word.length);
    document.getElementById('inputText').innerHTML = filterText;
}
```

**Html**

```
<body onload="makeALlIndex()">
       <div id="inputText">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.
<button onclick="changeColor(0,'')">click me</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: so you want to highlight the color of a specific text inside `innerHTML`?

Comment: yes, I am getting index only

Comment: on every change have to remove previous one because its reading effect

Comment: This has been asked a ton of times...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to highlight text using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript)

Comment: Why do you want to pass the index and the word? If you know the index, you can find the word, no? Does the index take into account the characters that make up the tags? Where do you get this index from?

Answer (score 0):

try to change your method to

```
function changeColor(index, word) {
   myText = defaultText;
   var filterText = myText.substring(0, index).split( word ).join( '<span  class="highlightClass">' + word + '</span>' ) +  myText.substr(index + word.length);
   document.getElementById('inputText').innerHTML = filterText;
}
```

Comment: its reloading my page when i comment 'document.getElementById('inputText').innerHTML = filterText;' its wokring fine but how i can replace the filtered html

Comment: @AliRaza didn't get `how i can replace the filtered html` part.

Comment: when I have my new html in `filterText ` so when i assign it to inner html it rerener my page.

Comment: @AliRaza what is the expected behaviour if changeColor is invoked again then?

Comment: remove previous highlighted word and apply to next word (represent by index)

Comment: @AliRaza isn't that what is happening?

Comment: Actually I need a funtion where I only can pass my index and it will turn highlight my that word witihin specific html <div>. that's all my problem there would be some jquery solution

Comment: @AliRaza how do you want the index to be used?

Comment: I have edited question. It was reloading because there is iframe which is reload video so that I am getting reloading effect.

Answer (score 0):

@Aliraza -

I think following solution will work for you

```
function changeColor(index, word) {
    myText = defaultText;
    var filterText = '',newText ='',myTextArray =[];
    if( myText.indexOf(word)!=-1){
        myTextArray = myText.split(word);
        for(i=0; i<= myTextArray.length-1;i++){  
           if(i==index){
               newText = myTextArray[i] + '<span  class="highlightClass">' + word + '</span>';
            }else {
               newText =  myTextArray[i];
            }
            filterText += newText;
       }    
        document.getElementById('inputText').innerHTML = filterText;
    }
}
```

It is based on the URL you have provided. Still there are lots of things you may need to change in it.