# How to wrap text not part of a tag in a tag?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to highlight (with `<mark`) a search string inside another string, but it shouldn't be part of a tag (i.e. `te` in `<cite>` shouldn't match, but `te` in `test` should). I've been using code like this to replace the match with the second regex listed, but that only works nestted.

```
someElement.innerHTML.replace(regex, function(full, before, match, after) {
  return before + '<mark>' + match + '</mark>' + after;
});
```

Suggestions I have tried:

- `<\/\w*>(\w*\s*)*(te)(\w*\s*)*<([a-z]*\s*\w*="\w*")*>` (doesn't match at all?)
- `(<.+?>[^<>]*?.*)(te)(.*[^<>]*?<.+?>)` (only works on the nested tags)
- `((<.+?>[^<>]*?)?.*)(te)(.*([^<>]*?<.+?>)?)` (`.replace` gives undefined's)

Example:

String to wrap: `te`

Input text:

```
‘This is a test string’
<cite> — some test wrapped too</cite>
```

Expected output:

```
‘This is a <mark>te</mark>st string’
<cite> — some <mark>te</mark>st wrapped too</cite>
```

I've browsed a lot of "duplicates", but couldn't find an exact one, but if someone can lead me to a working example, that'd be lovely too, thanks!

An answer that's now deleted which worked the best for me is `(te)(?![^<]*>)` (by revo). This does however not work if the next char is `>`, but I'll see that as a unsolved edge case.

Comment: Just use [mark.js](https://markjs.io)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to highlight text using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript)

Comment: @dude it's for the use in a light-weight library, so including another one seems not too smart of an idea. The duplicate you suggest doesn't fix the "in a tag name" problem I was having and revo solved.

Comment: @HaroenViaene: Are you sure - https://regex101.com/r/tW1dD3/1 ?

Comment: hmm, @WiktorStribiżew, that case *does* seem to be fixed when not entering the ` ` in the regex...

Comment: What if the text contains a `>`? Then again it won't work.

Comment: If there is no word character behind it then there is no problem too `(te)(?![^<> [:punct:]]*>)` @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @revo: JS RegExp does not support `[:punct:]`, nor any other POSIX character classes.

Comment: Yes I forgot about regex flavor `(te)(?!\w*>)` @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex:

```
(te)(?!\w*>)
```

It benefits from a negative lookahead to check if it is within an opening / closing tag or not. `(?!\w*>)` this will ignore any `te` that is followed by any word characters and `>` (which possibly denotes being within a tag name.)

### Failing case:

When there is potentially a string like `test>` (unpaired) within input string even though it is not a tag it doesn't match.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/pX7cN0/1)

Comment: What exactly is the point of the `  ` in the negative lookahead?

Comment: An space will avoid words like `test >` to be ignored since you may have a `>` within a literal text too. I modified regex to cover more possible cases.