# Wrap text in span tags knowing the start and end positions of the text

Tags: javascript, html

So I have following html:

```
<div class="container"> some beautiful text here </div>
```

What I want is:

```
<div class="container"> some <span class="highlight">beautiful</span> text <span class="highlight">here</span>
```

I know how to do it knowing the word. Thanks to this question: [How to highlight text using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript)
But I have to highlight text at specific positions. I have a start and end positions of the string. I've tried iterating through the list of start and end positions like this:

```
function highlight(divId, startPos, endPos) {
  inputText = document.getElementById(divId);
  var wholeText = inputText.innerText;
  var inHTML = wholeText.substring(0, startPos) + "<span class='highlight'>" + wholeText.substring(startPos, endPos-1) + "</span> " + wholeText.substring(endPos, wholeText.length);
  document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = inHTML;
}


function highlightAll(fileA, fileB, JSONfile) {
  var startPositionsA = extractStartPosA(JSONfile);
  var endPositionsA = extractEndPosA(JSONfile);
  var startPositionsB = extractStartPosB(JSONfile);
  var endPositionsB = extractEndPosB(JSONfile);

  for(var i=0; i < startPositionsA.length; i++) {
    highlight("TextA", startPositionsA[i]-1, endPositionsA[i]);
  }

  for(var i=0; i < startPositionsB.length; i++) {
    highlight("TextB", startPositionsB[i]-1, startPositionsB[i]);
  }
}
```

But the innerhtml is re-written after every iteration, so in the end I just get one single word highlighted - the one that is left after the last iteration.

Could anyone please help me? I do not have any ideas where to go further. Thank you!

Comment: Well then don’t overwrite innerHTML, but add to it …?

Comment: @CBroe can you please give me a hint how can I do it?

Comment: The indices always change after adding a <span></span> tag...

Comment: Well how do you add something to a string variable in JavaScript …? `foo = foo + "bar"`, or `foo += "bar"` for short.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if yout get the correct position in startPosition and endPosition you can create a var containing the highlighting:

```
var highlightStart = "<span class='highlight'>";
var highlightEnd = "</span>";
```

just split your text at the positions into parts and put together the parts and the highlighting vars in the correct order

Comment: glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
function highlight(id, start, end) {
 var html = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
 document.getElementById(id).innerHTML= [html.slice(0, start), '<span class="highlight">', html.slice(start, end), '</span>', html.slice(end)].join('');

}
```

Comment: well I have a similar function, but I have to iterate through the array of start and end positions, because I have a lot of words that I have to highlight, and every time I call this function inside of for-loop it just re-writes the innerHTML.