# Is there any way to change style properties of an input value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, input, text-styling

I have a form with a input.  When the user submits the form, i want the input value to change to be their input, but with some of it marked up.  the  want to differentiate part of an input value.  The charAt values of what i want to be differentiated is stored in an array.  This code doesn't  work, becuase characters don' t have style properties.  I have to work around that.

```
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            input.value.charAt(array[i]).style.color="red";
            input.value.charAt(array[i]).italics();
            input.value.charAt(array[i]).style.fontWeight="bold";
            input.value.charAt(array[i]).style.textDecoration="underline";
        }
```

Comment: You can't style particular elements in an array like that, where are you spitting out this code? link the html as well

Comment: `<input id="input/>`

Comment: @ChristopherMesser I know I can't, I'm looking for a way to work around it.

Comment: You could create an editable div (optionally style it like an input) and then highlight the characters with a solution like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript