# What is the proper way to make a paragraph with some words having different styles using CSS and javascript

Tags: javascript, css, styles, cpu-word

I have a paragraph with several long lines of texts. I need to apply a different style to some of the words. What would be the proper way to do this without creating too many tags?

How about when using a react-intl format message?

```
<div className="main"> 
  Select the Gear icon, and then choose Users > Manage users
</div>

.main {
  font-size:14px;
}
```

I want to apply styles to `Gear`, `Users` and `Manage users`.

Comment: I'd recommend wrapping each of your styled words with an `<i>` or `<span>` tag. I don't think there's any way around using tags.

Comment: Put the wrong close option since it's a duplicate of multiple examples but the first prerequisite of the site is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [attempting something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript) first if you're looking for dynamic javascript approach, or a simple html/css static approach like mentioned above. 

Answer (score 4):

You can use one of the built-in tags to achieve this.

- `<b>` - Bold text
- `<strong>` - Important text
- `<i>` - Italic text
- `<em>` - Emphasized text
- `<mark>` - Marked text
- `<small>` - Small text
- `<del>` - Deleted text
- `<ins>` - Inserted text
- `<sub>` - Subscript text
- `<sup>` - Superscript text

```css
.main {
  font-size:14px;
}
```

```html
<div className="main"> 
  Select the <b>Gear</b> icon, and then choose <b><i>Users</i></b> > <em><ins><sub>Manage users</sub></ins></em>
</div>
```

Or you can use the `span` tag to create inline elements in your text and then you can style them as you want.

```css
.main {
  font-size:14px;
}

#gear {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#users {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#manage-users {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: overline;
}
```

```html
<div className="main"> 
 Select the <span id="gear">Gear</span> icon, and then choose <span id="users">Users</span> > <span id="manage-users">Manage users</span>
</div>
```

**Update**

The code below is an example how to style each word differently when you use `react-intl FormattedMessage`.
[StackBlitz link.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kcewve?file=index.js)

```
render() {
    const style = {
      color: 'red',
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          <FormattedMessage
              id="userHint"
              defaultMessage={`Select the {gear} icon, and then choose {users} > {manageUsers}`}
              values={{
                gear: <b>Gear</b>, 
                users: <i>Users</i>, 
                manageUsers: <span style={style}>Manage users</span>
              }}
          />
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do it when using react-intl formatMessage

Comment: I just updated my answer. Please follow the StackBlitz link for a working demo.