# How to remove the extra space after the highlighted words?

Tags: javascript

I have a Function that gets a number and highlight that word number from a sentence.

The sentence would be in Persian and Right To Left. 
All words are separated by "|" in the sentence.

I'm using Arrays, because other common methods do not work on RTL texts, including the replace method in this post:
[How to highlight text using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript)

The problem is when the words are highlighted, there is an extra space after each word, which I don't need that to be highlighted.

I want to eliminate that, please.

I have prepared a demo in here:
https://liveweave.com/vp6YQi

```
function hilWrd(i) {
  var txt1 = document.getElementById( "RTL1" ).innerHTML;
  var txt2 = document.getElementById( "RTL2" );
  var ary = txt1.split("|");

  ary.splice( i-1, 0, "<span class='hil'>" );
  ary.splice( i-1 + 2, 0, "</span>" );
  txt2.innerHTML = ary.join(" ");  
}
```

expected result: to highlight "تست"
actual result: it highlights "تست "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of increasing the number of array elements, just wrap the word inside that particular array element:

```
ary[i-1] = "<span class='hil'>" + ary[i-1] + "</span>";
```

Demo - [Link](https://liveweave.com/cfB6V5)

Comment: Thank you so much! Your method perfectly works. 

Here is the working demo:
https://liveweave.com/jSUo0u