# Highlight and filter letters as i type on my webpage

Tags: html, filter

Hi I am really a super beginner at this. So i have scoured the internet a there are plenty solutions out there, however the guys giving the solutions assume you know this stuff and how to place it.

I tried so many solutions I have lost count. I tried a bunch a java scripts, I tried to copy and paste and then modify them and online tutorials are really not helpful because I really don't know what to do with the scripts (or how to implement). I will paste an example of one I tried.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var search = ['p', 'div', 'span'];

$("#highlighter").bind('key up', function(e){
var pattern = $(this).val();
```

I just need it to filter and highlight the letters I type on the web page that are in a table. For some reason the ones i have tried produce some really weird outputs, like showing your code as well as the content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to highlight text using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

when learning a programming-language you should start at the very basics. "... however the guys giving the solutions assume you know this stuff and how to place it" will follow you throughout the internet. If you want to use a script on a page you can use a script tag (see the example below).

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      console.log('hello world');
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

In your last sentence you describe a CTRL+F function for the web if I understand correctly. If you want to realize something like that, learning the basics of JavaScript will be necessary. Here is a link to a similar question asked by someone else: [How to highlight text using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript)

You can use the Search-function at the top to search for existing questions and the according answers. If you need any further help feel free to drop a comment.