# How to make search result like Google in JSF?

Tags: jsf, search, highlight

So, I want to display search result as I type the keyword and change the color of the search result text in JSF like when you use Google to search.

[Search example (WhatsApp)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB0Ka.png)

I've done the keyup part but still wonder how to apply highlight text using javascript in JSF.

Here is my xhtml code

```
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel value="Keyword "/>
        <h:inputText id="key" value="#{bookList.keyword}" style="height: 22px">
            <f:ajax event="keyup" render="search"/>
        </h:inputText>
        <h:commandButton value="SEARCH" action="index" styleClass="buttonSearch"/>
    </h:form>
    <br/>
    <h:dataTable value="#{bookList.books}" var="book" id="search"
                 class="book-table"
                 headerClass="book-table-header">
        <h:column>
            #{book.title}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            #{book.author}
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

and this is my java code...

> Constructor

```
public class Book {
private String title;
private String author;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public Book(String title, String author){
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
}
}
```

> Data

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BookList {

private String keyword = "";

public String getKeyword() {
    return keyword;
}

public void setKeyword(String keyword) {
    this.keyword = keyword;
}

private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>(
        Arrays.asList(
                new Book("My First Learn to Write Workbook", "Crystal Radke"),
                new Book("Where the Crawdads Sing", "Delia Owens"),
                new Book("Little Fires Everywhere: A Novel", "Celeste Ng"),
                new Book("Fortitude: American Resilience in the Era", "Dan Crenshaw"),
                new Book("Arguing the Socialists", "Glenn Beck"),
                new Book("Hidden Valley Road: Inside the Mind of an American Family", "Robert Kolker")
        )
);

public List<Book> getBooks() {
    if (keyword.equals("")) {
        return books;
    } else {
        List<Book> listSearch = new ArrayList<Book>();
        for(Book book:books){
            if(book.getAuthor().toLowerCase().contains(keyword.toLowerCase()) 
                    || book.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(keyword.toLowerCase())){
                listSearch.add(book);
            }
        }
        return listSearch;
    }
}

}
```

Sorry, if my question isn't nice.

Comment: Please add details about the efforts you have done to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]. It would be good to know where the data is saved? What type of data is it? etc. This [javascript highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript) may help you.

Comment: My advice would be to buy the jsf for javaee8 book by Bauke Scholtz (BalusC)

Comment: Is this enough? @akg179

Comment: @fuggerjaki61 it is String[]. I think I can work it out after opening your link, but I wonder how to use javascript in JSF.

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks, I'll check it out after this pandemic end.

Comment: If you wonder how to use Javascript with JSF you should take some tutorials (or books) how to use them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to highlight text using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript)