# Highlighting Partial Text in the Input Element Tag without using Div contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, angular, google-chrome-devtools, angular2-directives

I have a form in which there are input elements of type text that may contain text starting with **@**, now what I want to achieve is to highlight the partial text inside the input elements that starts with **@**. I have seen other solutions like using div with **contenteditable** and other solutions like using editor that does work but they changes the actual content with the HTML and this is not what I don't want to use.

Now I have noticed chrome implements find and highlight the text as shown in below image and that seems I can modifify its logic with my requirements,

[image: Highlight on search]

[image: other example]

Is there any hints or solutions ? Please help me with this case.

Comment: Do you want to style them a certain way, or are you trying to actually select the text (.e.g. to copy it)?

Comment: I want to style them in a certain way like highlighting them, see a second image like that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66899473/highlight-specific-words-in-textarea-angular-8

Comment: Duplicate! [Highlighting text within an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67119347/highlighting-text-within-an-input-field)

Comment: Sorry @NebojsaNebojsa, but see this line in a question -> I have noticed Chrome implements find and highlight the text as shown in the below image and that seems I can modify its logic with my requirements. I think it is possible to do it in the way I mentioned in the question. So this way the question may seem similar but is different, also please refer to the images.

Comment: @NebojsaNebojsa, all the solutions to that question are contenteditable that may fulfill the requirement of that question nor that question mentioned that it do not want to use contenteditable as I mentioned, this is because using contenteditable changes the actual content of input text with html tags and that is what I dont want, so again I can say my question may seem similar but is different, please help me with this case. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the following:

```js
function updateSpanText() {
  const input = document.querySelector(".input");
  const highlightedText = document.querySelector(".highlighted-text");
  const highlightedTextContent = input.value.replace(/@(\w+)/g, '<span class="highlight">@$1</span>');
  highlightedText.innerHTML = highlightedTextContent;
}

function onFocus() {
  const highlightedText = document.querySelector(".highlighted-text");
  highlightedText.style.display = 'none';
}

function onBlur() {
  const highlightedText = document.querySelector(".highlighted-text");
  highlightedText.style.display = 'inline-block';
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.input-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.highlighted-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  top: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <input class="input" type="text" onblur="onBlur()" onfocus="onFocus()" onchange="updateSpanText()" />
  <span class="highlighted-text"></span>
</div>
```

The idea is that you keep track of the input-value and once you are done editing, you layer the rendered text on top of the input. When you are actually editing, you just display the input itself.

With `pointer-events: none` we can prevent the span from catching events so all events are received by the input.

Comment: Yes, this seems one more good way to do it, let me try this too. Do you think we can also do something like a browser do it finds and highlight including the input tag?

Comment: No, we cannot do it with simple input elements. It is not meant for that use-case. If you want more advanced features use a textarea instead. But you can style the textarea to look more or less like a regular input so ... You can also use WebComponents and create your own input element but I'd not recommend that.

Comment: @ABC You may want to checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::highlight but this is a draft and it does not work on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style substrings of a true text field. If you want to keep the input for functionality reasons but show the user a styled field, you can have a `contenteditable` on top with a hidden input on the bottom and bind them so that the raw text gets submitted in the input but your contenteditable is just for show.

Example case:

```js
function setCaret(el, childNode, index) {
  var range = document.createRange();
  var sel = window.getSelection();

  range.setStart(childNode, index);
  range.collapse(true);

  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}

function getSelectedElement() {
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  var tag = range.startContainer.parentNode;
  
  console.log(tag);
  
  return tag;
}

document.querySelector('#name-editor').addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  var $self = document.querySelector('#name-editor');

  if (event.key == '@') {
    event.preventDefault();
    $self.appendChild(document.createElement('span')).className = 'highlight';
    $self.lastChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode('@'));
    setCaret($self, $self.lastChild, 1);
  }
  
  if (event.keyCode == 32 && getSelectedElement().className.indexOf('highlight') > -1) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $self.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
    $self.lastChild.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
    setCaret($self, $self.lastChild, 1);
  }
});

document.querySelector('#name-editor').addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  document.querySelector('#name-field').value = this.textContent.trim();
  console.log(document.querySelector('#name-field').value);
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 200, .3);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0.1);
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="name-field" type="text" name="name" style="display: none;" />
  Name: <div id="name-editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
</form>
```