# JS: Search a string in object and add a class to it

Tags: css, vue.js, object

I got some objects in my vue app and i want to wrap a specific string within this object into a `<span class="myClass">mySearchedStringInObject</span>` to add a class to this string for some highlighting of this searched string. After that, i pass that object as a prop to another component in my vue app and display the object values there (also to newly highlited string).

I have absolutley no idea how to do this, can anybody help me out here?

Comment: This has been asked a thousand times. See something like https://markjs.io/, if you have no idea how to implement yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to highlight text using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript)