# Format of some words within {{$t('msg')}}

Tags: vue.js

I'm writing a webpage which requires localisation. So I need to put paragraphs into variables:

index.vue

```html
      <div class="descrip">
        <p class="dTitle">{{$t('message.instructionTitle')}}</p>
        <p>{{$t('message.instructionFirst')}}</p>
        <p>{{$t('message.instructionSecond')}}</p>
        <p>{{$t('message.instructionThird')}}</p>
        <p>{{$t('message.instructionForth')}}</p>
        <p>{{$t('message.instructionFifth')}}</p>
      </div>
```

index.js

```js
const messages = {
  en: {
    message: {
      instructionFirst: "Hello, world!",
      instructionSecond: "...",
      //...
    },
  },
  jp: {
    message: {
      //...
    },
  },
  //..
};
export default messages;
```

If I want to add some style (e.g. `color=red`) to **some words within** the paragraph (e.g. `message.instructionFirst`), what should I do besides separate those words from `message.instructionFirst`?

---

Edit:

For example, `instructionFirst` is like:

Hello, world!

I want:

```html
Hello, <mark style="color:red;">world</mark>!
```

Comment: Whats `<style="color:red;">`?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It's only a way to show that "world" is red here. I don't know how to give it a color in Stack Overflow...

Comment: once you work out why/how the word *world* will be hightlighted you can then use js, then use `v-html="highlight($t('message.instructionFirst'), $t('message.instructionFirstWord'))"` to render it, instructionFirstWord *or similar* being the word in the specific lang, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript make a method/mixin/component etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67660579/format-of-some-words-within-tmsg#comment119598173_67660579), you could use a component method to wrap the target words with the styled markup, and use `v-html` to apply the results:

1. Create a method (named `"highlight"`) that searches a given string for a word, and returns HTML that surrounds the target words with the desired markup:

   ```js
   export default {
     methods: {
       highlight(searchWord, input) {
         return input.replace(new RegExp(searchWord, 'ig'), w => `<mark style="color:red">${w}</mark>`)
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. In your template, use the [`v-html` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html) to bind the result of `highlight()` for each translation to a `p`'s `innerHTML`:

   ```html
   <p v-html="highlight($t('message.instructionFirstHighlight'), $t('message.instructionFirst'))"></p>
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/highlighting-a-substring-i5n6m?file=/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, how about the following lines:

```
const messages = {
  redKeys: ['instructionFirst'],
  en: {
    message: {
      //...
    },
  },
  jp: {
    message: {
      //...
    },
  },
  //..
};
export default messages;
```

then, replace your vue templates with the following lines:

```
     <div class="descrip">
        <p 
           v-for="(value, key, index) in message"
           v-key="index"
           :class="{
             dTitle: key === 'message.instructionTitle'
             red: redKeys.includes[key],
           }"
        >{{$t(value)}}</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: I am sorry that you might misunderstood what I meant. I want **some words within** `instructionFirst` to be red, not the whole `instructionFirst` to be red. (See updated question)