# How to avoid affecting HTML tags in childNodes during innerHTML string.replace()?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, innerhtml

I am aiming to replace each word in a document P tags with a span element. While the below code does the trick well for the first case, the following ones overlap, and start to destroy the HTML structure of our P tag completely. [See image for unwanted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh7Tt.jpg)

Wondering if my approach is a wrong one, or would need some sorcery to only effect the innerHTML between the tags?

```
const runBionic = (node: ChildNode, paragraph: HTMLElement):HTMLElement => {
if (node.textContent === null) return paragraph;
const originalWords:string[] = node.textContent.split(" ");
const filteredWords: string[] = originalWords.filter(word => word!=="" && word !== "\n");
console.log("Filtered words: ", filteredWords);
//replace each word with a span element
filteredWords.forEach(word => {
    const modifiedWord = `<span style='font-weight: bold;'>${word}</span>`;
    console.log("REPLACING ", word, "WITH ", modifiedWord);
    paragraph.innerHTML = paragraph.innerHTML.replaceAll(word,modifiedWord);
});
return paragraph;};
```

Aiming to eventually build a chrome extension that highlights the first 1/2 of the characters of any word on any page. This will help dyslexic people read the web faster. Attaching a link to the whole [repo on github](https://github.com/ekkuleivonen/power-reader) for context.

Comment: dealing with innerHTML like that is not ideal - almost as bad as using regex on html (don't do that either) - seems you may be better off with processing the textContent of every node inside the given node using `node.querySelectorAll('*')`

Comment: Thanks @Bravo! However the  textContent property is only for text as the name suggests. I cannot insert html into it... This would lead to the client rendering "<span>myword</span>".  Or am I wrong here?

Comment: ahh, yes ... I didn't think quite fully :p

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644428/how-to-highlight-text-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I ended up with replacing the whole TextNode with a new span element instead. This way I can prepare the whole element and append it to its parent. Works perfectly, no regex needed....

```
const replaceNode = (node: ChildNode)=>{
if (node.textContent === null) return node;
const newChild = document.createElement("span");
const words: string[] = node.textContent.split(" ").filter(word => word!=="" && word !== "\n");
const HTMLstring: string = spannify(words);
newChild.innerHTML = HTMLstring;
return newChild;};

const spannify = (words : string[]) : string=>{
let HTMLstring = "";
words.forEach(word =>{
    const span = `<span> ${word} </span>`;
    HTMLstring += span;
});
return HTMLstring;};
```

Comment: This only works for elements that don't contain child nodes though

Comment: @Bergi you are correct! This function actually takes in only the child nodes of an element which I’m interested in replacing. See the repo on GitHub for more context.