# JS: Record user selections in html with multiples occurrence

Tags: javascript

> I'm trying to record what the user is highlighting in a node, giving that they can be multiples children nodes and that part of text can be duplicated and need to be differentiated.

```
<div id="blob">
   <p>this is a text with lots of <b>content</b>!</p>
   <p>There can be <span>lots</span> of paragraph and weird things</p>
   <p>there are duplicates in the text:</p>
   <p>this is a text with lots of <b>content</b>!</p>
   <div>The goal is to record the text selected, and know it's position 
   (n° of occurrence) in the all blob of text</div>
</div>
```

For example, if the user would selected 'with lots of content', I need to know which part of the text it refer too.

My current implementation is to put tags on the selection text, and look for theirs positions relative to the overall text, and the index of the research of the selected text. However it seems hacky, it requires to modify the html. is there a way to do without it?

It's related to ["javascript-find-occurance-position-of-selected-text-in-a-div"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558527/javascript-find-occurance-position-of-selected-text-in-a-div)
but without the assumption that the parent node is a text node.

Comment: You would need html wrappers(span,div) around the words. Without them it would be impossible to highlight the text.

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816308/how-to-highlight-html-text-without-wrapping-it-with-tags

Comment: this would be helpful http://jsfiddle.net/Vap7C/15/